# Adding mp4 mime-type prevents streaming of video with Unicorn and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, video, unicorn

I'm seeing some strange behaviour where an .mp4 video file (located in /assets/images/) streams perfectly well without anything registered in mime_types.rb. But, **if I register the video/mp4 mime-type, the video will not stream.**

mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register "video/mp4", :mp4
```

Safari displays the first picture of the video, but cannot stream the video. This is only an issue with Safari and only with Unicorn (not Webrick).

We need the mime-type registered, because we're responding to mp4 requests in other locations of the app.

Any ideas how to solve this?

- Rails 4.1.3
- Ruby 2.1.2
- Unicorn 4.8.3

Video details from `ffmpeg -I`

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'background_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2015-03-06 14:03:09
    encoder         : Lavf54.6.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 893 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1114x494, 903 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-06 14:03:09
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-06 14:03:09
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the videos files to the /public/ folder fixes the issue.